# "Parishioner" vs. "congregant"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nouns, word-usage

I've always thought that the words *parishioner* and *congregant* meant the same thing and could be used interchangeably within the context of someone who attends a place of worship. Are there any differences in meaning between these two words or appropriate usage for each?

Comment: I wonder if it is a coincidence that [this question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Language#Can_these_words_be_used_interchangeably.3F_.28churchgoer.2C_church_member.2C_parishioner.2C_etc..29) has been asked and discussed within the last week.

Comment: What research did you do, please?

Very roughly, is it not true that a "parishioner" need only live in the parish but a "congregant" is one who at leat attends church services?

Comment: In the UK, and hence in British English, a **parishioner** is any person who lives within a parish. A **parish** was *a territorial subdivision of a diocese having its own priest, parson, or other incumbent under the jurisdiction of a bishop.* (OED) A further distinction came in the 17th century in which the word *parish* could describe a unit area of civil government that might or might not coincide with the parish of a church/a vicar, etc. A **congregant** is a member of the congregation of any Church/church/religion/place of worship.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Parishioner* and *congregant* refer to *members* of a particular local faith community. The requirements for membership, of course, vary considerably, but for the most part, simply attending services at a church does not make one a parishioner or congregant of that church any more than visiting a country makes one a citizen of it.

Sectarian considerations govern which is the more appropriate term.

*Parishioner* is older by a good measure. A parish is an ecclesiastical territory, a section of an episcopal see (e.g. a diocese or archdiocese). Traditionally, any inhabitant of that territory would have been expected to attend services at the local parish church, and all would have been parishioners. The Catholic, Anglican, and Orthodox churches remain organized in this manner, but the term "parish" is used even by some denominational bodies without episcopal administration, so making the members parishioners.

*Congregant* is broader, in that it refers to the regular members of any local congregation. That local congregation may be a parish, but it might also be a local church or meeting house of a tradition that does not use the term *parish*, such as the Baptists or Mormons— or for that matter, Muslims or Jews.

To refer more generally to those attending services at a particular time, you could simply say *worshippers* or *attendees*; for all adherents, there are a variety of terms employed, such as *the brethren* or *the faithful*, or the more mundane *churchgoers* or *the observant*; *communicants* captures the sense of those in communion with the Church as opposed to outsiders.

Comment: What an awesome response, +1 (and a checkmark)!

Answer (score 8):

A [*parish*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/parish) is the territory corresponding to a church.  If I live in that territory and attend that church, I am a [*parishioner*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/parishioner) of that church, and also a [*congregant*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/congregant).  If I live outside that territory, but still attend that church, I am one of its congregants, but not one of its parishioners.

Comment: You could also be a _parishoner_ if you live in the parish but **not** a _congregant_ if you do not attend services in the church. If you were talking about the Church of England parish you would, as a parishoner, be entitled to be married in the church even if you were not a congegant.

Answer (score 3):

In the US and US state territory under Common Law, parishioners are associated with residency within extra-governmental, quasi-jurisdictional, territorial divisions, called parishes--these are separate and apart from, and subordinate to, state territorial political divisions and instrumentalities--under jurisdiction of an  hierarchically structured religious institution, most notably, the Roman Catholic Church  headquartered in Rome, but also of derivative and offshoot organizations--but, as established under Amendment 1, the US Constitution, only insofar as any such resident is or voluntarily becomes a pledged or "customary" adherent (a congregant) subject to the aims, teachings, doctrines, authority, and jurisdiction of said parish's congregation, both clergy and laity, as represented, headquartered, housed and served by a permanent church, Cathredal, mission, temple, ....

Tracing from feudal times when Church and State vied for primacy, demarcations of parish boundaries today are of a generally more ill-defined, more fluid, more ad hoc nature. In the abstract, it could be said that spatial density distribution of church member and attendee residency as between one parish and a neighboring parish in large measure defines inter-parish boundaries, with one exception. Under Romanic law in Louisiana, parish and political subdivisions coincide: parishes (for example, the Parish of New Orleans) take the place of county and county subdivisions. (Incidentally, the best known distinction as between Common and Romanic Law, respectfully, is the presumption of innocence and of guilt.)

Except for association with a territory, the word *congregant* subsumes and is readily exchangeable with the ascription *parishioner*. An active parishioner is a congregant. A congregant is not necessarily a parishioner.

Answer (score 2):

I am the member of a two point parish--in that, two separate church congregations share one pastor and all of the costs associated with our pastor--and that pastor shares his/her time between the two congregations.  Therefore, I am the congregant of my individual church; however, I am also a parishioner of the total parish.

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes interchangeable, but not always. A member of a Catholic church or Jewish synagogue, for example, could be congregants (they congregate, or gather) but not parishioners, as there is no parish, no pastor. 
Parishioner usually connotates a Protestant, which we have many of in the USA.

Comment: Almost all words used by Protestant denominations originated in Catholic usage, including *parish* and *pastor*. (The only exception I can think of off the top of my head is *minister*, which *was* used pre-Reformation, just not with a religious connotation.)

Comment: What! The  Parish of St. Luke where my son worshipped, and its pastor Fr. Stolz, were **impostors**! I shall certainly have to have words with the Archbishop of St. Louis—unless he's an impostor, too.

Comment: Isn't everybody in Louisiana a parishioner regardless of religious affiliation? MW definition #3: "PARISH : a civil division of the state of Louisiana corresponding to a county in other state" [link](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parish) & " PARISHIONER : a member or inhabitant of a parish" [link](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parishioner?show=0&t=1350429663)

Comment: I don't know where you got this information, but in the US, individual Catholic church communities are universally known as parishes and their members as parishioners.

Comment: That's because Catholic churches do have territorial parishes.