# How would I address people who attend church with me?

Tags: single-word-requests

So I am a christian and attend church. How would I grammatically refer to people who also attend my church. Fellow church mates, church-goer, church attendee?

A fellow ______ gave me a job at her business.

Comment: Churchgoer is the one I'd use.

Comment: They're "people who go to the same church as I do".  If your church has parishes you might refer to them as "fellow parishioners", and there are likely other terms specific to different religions.

Comment: A "fellow congregant?" "Someone you know from church?"

Comment: Yes. I am trying to say how a fellow churchgoer offered me a job in my college essay

Comment: A "fellow flock member" ? *A "flock" is a group of people under the leadership of one person, especially the members of a church*.

Comment: A fellow “***in the congregation***”.    But most people would just say “a guy in my church” ...  Or “a guy from my church”

Comment: The least marked might be member. It also depends on what denomination you are. Different denominations use different terms. Quakers are Friends, for instance.

Comment: I am pentecostal if it matters, but I don't think it does. In my essay, I currently use churchgoer. ..."a fellow churchgoer, Laura, offered me a job at her warehouse."

Comment: A fellow *worshiper*.

Comment: Although I understand it may have a different conotation in english, have you considered *cultist*? In portuguese (my native language) it isn't at all derogatory. But I subscribe @JohnClifford's suggestion of *churchgoer*.

Comment: This may depend on whether you are trinitarian or non-trinitarian, for some of the latter group (at least back in the 80s) opposed the word 'church' on the grounds that it begged association with other denominations.  If members of your fellowship do commonly use the word, then 'churchgoer' seems a logical choice.

Comment: I would say "fellow churchgoer".

Comment: There is a distinct difference in implication between churchgoer and parishioner. A fellow churchgoer is anyone who also goes to church -- any church, not necessarily the same one I go to. A fellow parishioner, on the other hand, is someone who goes to my parish. Different denominations, however, definitely have different terminology. Not all use "parish". Some seem to cast the whole sentence differently and would say, "someone who goes to my church" or "someone from my church".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *congregant* is a a member of a congregation, so I might say “a fellow congregant,” though that does sound quite formal.

Here is [Merriam-Webster's entry](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/congregant):

> **congregant** *n* | con·gre·gant | \ˈkäŋ-gri-gənt\
>   : a person who is part of a congregation : a person who is attending religious services or who regularly attends religious services
>   :  one who congregates; specifically :  a member of a congregation

It's similar to *parishioner*. See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87093/parishioner-vs-congregant) for discussion of the two.

Answer (score 2):

To take up the suggestion that Hot Licks makes in a comment above, *parishioner* might be an appropriate term for you to use. Here is the entry for *parishioner* in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003):

> **parishioner** *n* (15c) **:** a member or inhabitant of a parish

and here is the same dictionary's entry for *parish*:

> **parish** *n* (14c) **1 a** (1) **:** the ecclesiastical unit of area committed to one pastor (2) : the residents of such an area **b** *Brit* **:** a subdivision of  county  often coinciding  with an original ecclesiastical parish and constituting the unit of local government **2 :** a local church community  composed of the members or constituents of a Protestant church **3 :** a civil division of the state of Louisiana corresponding to a county in other states

So if definitions 1a(1), 1a(2), or 2 of *parish* apply in your situation, the term *parishioner* may be a good choice to fill in the blank in the sentence you provide:

> A fellow ______ gave me a job at her business.

Answer (score 0):

A fellow Christian would seem logical to me.  I've heard many BAC refer to thier friends or church mates in sentences such as, "Oh,  you would really like her, she's a fellow Christian."

A fellow Believer.

Or depending on the strength of the relationship would you ever feel comfortable saying my "brother" or "sister"?